# How to avoid noise in YHDC SCT-013-000 current transformer?

Tags: arduino, noise, calibration, current-transformer

I have a SCT-013-000 current transformer which I have connected to Arduino Uno with a burden resistor of 33 ohms and the calibration value I am using is 60. 
The problem is we are getting current values even after the load is switched is off/ power supply is off. Example when we are testing with 60W bulb the power values that are sensed are much higher. 
As check for solution its been mentioned that the CT will work more accurate for higher current values.

Can experts please, suggest what can be done to get proper readings for lower currents.

[image]

Comment: Schematic of your CT interface circuit is needed.

Comment: Also you need to explain what the error reading is. You are showing 147 A on the CT, presumably full-scale input. A 60 W lamp on 230 V will draw about 1/4 A, about 0.2% of full scale. Are your circuit expectations realistic?

Comment: We are getting the Current values of about 0.59 A when the current is passing and around 0.45 A when the switch is off.

Comment: How much current is measured when the phase wire is removed from the current transformer? The initial current flowing through a cold bulb is much larger than that computed from power and voltage. Just measure the bulb cold resistance using a multimeter. Did you read the datasheet of the used current transformer very carefully?

Comment: The SCT-013-000 is for 100 A. Non- linearity is +- 3 % for the range 10%—120% of rated input current. You got no information about non-linearity for currents less than 10 A. The current for 60 W is 0.27 A. You should use a test load with 2.2 kW or more.